# I am Using Jbuttons on Jpanel and addding this jpanel on Jlist. I am using addMouseListener on list. Not able to get click on Button on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

Below is the minimum reproducible code. In MouseClicked method with mouseevent i got that Jpanel is clicked by using getelementat() method.
But which button on JPanel is clicked can not figure. Tried with convert point but making some mistake. Need to check which button on Jpanel is clicked. Need some help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class JListTest {
    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel dataModel ;
    private JTableTest tableTest;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public JListTest() {
        dataModel = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList<>(dataModel);

        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JList target = (JList) me.getSource();
                        int index = target.locationToIndex(me.getPoint());
                        JPanel item = (JPanel) target.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                        Point p=SwingUtilities.convertPoint(target,me.getPoint(),item);
                        item.getComponentAt(p);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        list.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());

    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        JListTest test=new JListTest();
        test.dataModel.addElement("Lable 1");
        test.dataModel.addElement("Lable 2");
        test.dataModel.addElement("Lable 3");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        
        test.panel.add(button1);
        test.panel.add(button2);
        test.dataModel.addElement(test.panel);
        test.showUi();
    }
    public void showUi(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo list");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setType(Window.Type.UTILITY);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if(value instanceof String){
                return new DefaultListCellRenderer().getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
            }

            return (Component) value;
        }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Please tell us the details of your code and your problem in your question not in the code comments

Comment: Also you're asking about a button click but showing a mouse listener added to a jlist not an action listener added to a button.

Comment: Button click is not working as Jlist not passing the click to Jbutton. And inside mouseClicked it gives me Jpanel is clicked , but i need to know which button on JPanel is clicked.

Comment: To respond to changes in a JList’s selection, do not use a MouseListener.  Use [addListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener)) for that.

Comment: A JList doesn't display real components so there are no events generated for the buttons on the panel. Not sure if it will work buy you can try: 1) getting the JPanel using the `getSelectedValue()` method of the JList. Then you would need to covert the mouse point to be relative to the panel using the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method. Then you would need to use the `findComponentAt(....)` method.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @camickr thanks for the help, i can get the selected item by getSelectedValue() but still not able to convertPoint to child element. There is JPanel with two buttons on jlist item.  i know jpanel is clicked but do not know which button is clicked.

Comment: *still not able to convertPoint to child element.* - still waiting for an [mre] showing what you have tried. Did you verify that you can get the location of components on the selected panel.

Comment: @camickr Adding minimal reproducible example

Comment: +1, for posting a reasonable MRE. -1, for not doing any debugging of the code. Take the time to understand the suggestions given and figure out why they might not be working. For example, did you display the value of the converted point? Did the x/y values make sense? They didn't make sense for me, so you need to figure out why they do not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.getComponentAt(p);
```

What is the point of that statement? How can you tell if the code worked or not since you never assign the result of the method to a variable?

Turns out that because the panel is not really a component displayed on the frame you can't just do as I originally suggested.

If you add code like:

```
JPanel item = (JPanel) target.getModel().getElementAt(index);
System.out.println( item.getBounds() );
```

You get output like:

> java.awt.Rectangle[x=-487,y=-36,width=0,height=0]

Which doesn't make any sense.

So, I changed the logic to assign the bounds to the panel as if it was displayed on the JList:

```
item.setBounds(target.getCellBounds(index, index));
```

Now, I get output like:

> java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=54,width=487,height=36]

Which does make more sense. However, that still doesn't help because if you add:

```
Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(target,me.getPoint(),item);
System.out.println( p );
```

You get something like:

> java.awt.Point[x=834,y=166]

The conversion of the point does do what I expected.

So, I decided to convert the point manually:

```
int y = me.getY() - item.getBounds().y;
Point p = new Point(me.getX(), y);
```

Putting it all together you get something like:

```
JList target = (JList) me.getSource();
int index = target.locationToIndex(me.getPoint());
JPanel item = (JPanel) target.getModel().getElementAt(index);
item.setBounds(target.getCellBounds(index, index));
int y = me.getY() - item.getBounds().y;
Point p = new Point(me.getX(), y);
JButton button = (JButton)item.getComponentAt(p);
System.out.println(button.getText());
```

And you get the text of the button when you click on it.

Of course, you get Exceptions if you click anywhere else. I'll leave it up to you do handle the Exception logic.

Note, I see your latest question is about adding labels and a panel to a frame. It is a much better approach to use real components as you can add ActionListeners to your buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the help and guidance. This is working with some exceptions. Actually need to show this ui And on click of button i need to add some ui below this. And regarding the new post , yes i will try to work with multiple panels on frame. Thanks.