# How to capture buttonClick event in JList defaultListModel ? And also how to customise width of jbutton inside defaultListModel "Capture it's click !"

Tags: java, swing

Here is a sample code for the same, the button "Capture it's click !" is inside defaultListModel and a click on this is percieved as click on list element, however I need this click as button click event. And is there any way to reduce the width of this button. Currently width is same as list element.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class JListTest {
    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel dataModel;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public JListTest() {
        dataModel = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList<>(dataModel);
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("mouse event==" + me);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        list.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JListTest test = new JListTest();
        test.dataModel.addElement("Lable 1");
        test.dataModel.addElement(createButton("Capture it's click !"));
        test.dataModel.addElement("Lable 3");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(" button 1 clieck");
            }
        });
        test.panel.add(button1);
        test.panel.add(button2);
        test.dataModel.addElement(test.panel);
        test.showUi();
    }

    public void showUi() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo list");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setType(Window.Type.UTILITY);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (value instanceof JButton) {
                ((JButton) value).setBackground(isSelected ? Color.GRAY : list.getBackground());

                int listSize = list.getModel().getSize();
                if (listSize > 10 && index < listSize - 4) {
                    if (list.getModel().getElementAt(index) instanceof JButton) {
                        ((JButton) list.getModel().getElementAt(index)).setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (value instanceof String) {
                return new DefaultListCellRenderer().getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            }

            return (Component) value;
        }
    }

    public static JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setBounds(80, 30, 10, 40);
        // button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call createButton() method? I would go on and create a CustomButton Class which extends JButton and implements ActionListener. You can set the dimension preferences and override actionPerformed() method in there, and then just create Object from CustomButton in your list

Comment: @zozinski createButton() method is called from   test.dataModel.addElement(createButton("Capture it's click !")); while adding element into defaultListModel.

Comment: I have also tried to create a customButton class and override the method actionPerformed, but still I do not get the event in actionPerformed.

Comment: A renderer is not a real component. There is no event generated when clicking on the button.  If you need a single column, then you can use a JTable which supports the concept of an editor which will allow you to handle a click on the button. Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for an example.

Comment: I can not use table either, My requirement is like I will have 3-4 lines of information in Jlist and then based on the information, I need to add single or multiple buttons below this. Click on this button will again add 3-4 lines into Jlist and again we will have single or multiple buttons. That is the reason I need to add a button in Jlist which I have done but the main challenge is to capture it's event. On click of this button, it seems like I can only capture Jlist mouseClick event.

Comment: *it seems like I can only capture Jlist mouseClick event.* - I already stated that is exactly the case. The button is not a real component, so no event is generated. I made a suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73773176/131872 on how you might be able to know when you click in the area represented by the button.